# C++ How do I keep track of spaces in a string, and then print their index location +1 at the end?

Tags: c++

I am writing a program where I need to keep track of how many spaces I have, and where the index location is +1.

So for instance my string goes like this:

```
string msg = "this is my message"
```

and I have 3 spaces, each located at index 4, 7, and 10

I need the end result to look like:

> this is my message&5#8#11

which is index location +1

I currently have:

```
int numspace;
numspace = msg[i] == 32;
```

and

```
string space;
space = msg[i+1];
```

Which I know is wrong, I just can't seem to get past this hurdle I've made for myself.

Thanks, 
shannon

Answer (score 0):

For tracking space locations use `std::vector`. Iterate over a `std::string` and if you encounter space, push the index into the `std::vector`.

```
std::vector<int> spaceLocations;
for (int i = 0; i < msg.size(); ++i)
    if (msg[i] == ' ')
        spaceLocations.push_back(i + 1);
```